# accordions are disappearing when I open the accordion beside it and disappearing after I close that accordion

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I'm using accordions for my site (as seen in [this video](https://vimeo.com/783233992)), but when I open a accordion, the accordion beside it opens as well and when I close it, the accordion beside it disappears

I don't know why this happens.
(PS: ignore the snow that was just some testing)

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-card");
var i;

      for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
          /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
    to highlight the button that controls the panel */
          this.classList.toggle("active");
    
          /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
          var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
          if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
          } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
          }
        });
      }
```

```
.accordion-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.accordion-card {
  background-color: rgba(182, 210, 253, 0.041);
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 30vw;
  max-width: 385px;
  min-width: 350px;
  /*height: 70px;*/
  border: 1px solid rgba(153, 196, 239, 0.121);
  position: relative;
}

.accordion-header {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.841);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem 0.8rem 1.3rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(153, 196, 239, 0.121);*/
}

.accordion-content {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.658);
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1rem;
  /*padding-top: 1rem;*/
  /*padding-bottom: 1rem;*/
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1.3rem;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  /* hide the content until shown */
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.accordion-header::after {
  content: '\003E';
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
}

.accordion-card.active .accordion-content {
  height: 150px;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1.3rem;
}

.accordion-card.active .accordion-header::after{
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
```

```
          <div class="accordion-wrapper">
            <div class="accordion-card">
              <div class="accordion-header">
                Card 1
              </div>
              <div class="accordion-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque
                nesciunt vero sunt. Ad eveniet maiores quidem quis id animi
                dolor sequi perspiciatis blanditiis ut provident vel unde
                aliquam.
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="accordion-card">
              <div class="accordion-header">Card 2</div>
              <div class="accordion-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque
                nesciunt vero sunt. Ad eveniet maiores quidem quis id animi
                dolor sequi perspiciatis blanditiis ut provident vel unde
                aliquam.
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="accordion-card">
              <div class="accordion-header">Card 3</div>
              <div class="accordion-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque
                nesciunt vero sunt. Ad eveniet maiores quidem quis id animi
                dolor sequi perspiciatis blanditiis ut provident vel unde
                aliquam.
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="accordion-card">
              <div class="accordion-header">Card 4</div>
              <div class="accordion-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque
                nesciunt vero sunt. Ad eveniet maiores quidem quis id animi
                dolor sequi perspiciatis blanditiis ut provident vel unde
                aliquam.
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="accordion-card">
              <div class="accordion-header">Card 5</div>
              <div class="accordion-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque
                nesciunt vero sunt. Ad eveniet maiores quidem quis id animi
                dolor sequi perspiciatis blanditiis ut provident vel unde
                aliquam.
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="accordion-card">
              <div class="accordion-header">Card 6</div>
              <div class="accordion-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque
                nesciunt vero sunt. Ad eveniet maiores quidem quis id animi
                dolor sequi perspiciatis blanditiis ut provident vel unde
                aliquam.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

I expected only the accordion I opened to open, not others beside it. Also, if any of you guys could help me solve the problem of them disappearing unexpectedly, that would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems in you code:

1. I'm not sure why you are toggling the visibility of the next Sibling element in JS. This is what causes the blocks to disappear.

```js
          /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
          var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
          if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
          } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
          }
```

Removing this part of the code now resolves the blocks disappearing.

2. The blocks now stop disappearing, but they still "open". They don't really open they just stretch their titles, because of the CSS Flex. There is easy CSS solution for that:

```css
.accordion-card {
    max-height: 70px;
}
.accordion-card.active {
    max-height: none;
}
```

We fix the max-height to 70px for all, so they don't get enlarged. and remove the max height for the active one. Then only the active one will have full height.

Here is a working JS Filled example with all the changes.

https://jsfiddle.net/s612pbmk/1/